# Preventing $.post form information from appearing in url

Tags: jquery, url, post

I have a website which will have some personal data. When I use $.post the message is appended to the URL. So `index.html` becomes `index.html?message=Hey+what's+up%3F` upon submitting the form. How do I prevent this behavior?

The jQuery:

```
$(form1Var).submit(function() {                     
    $.post("submit.php", form1Var.serialize(), function(data) {
        var code = data.trim();
        console.log(code);
        $('[data-role="response"]').html('<span class="ui-btn-text">' + code + '</span>');
        $('[data-role="submit"]').load("submit_form.html");
    });
});
```

The form:

```
<form name="submit_message" action="" id="message_form">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <label for="textarea" class="ui-input-text">Message:</label>
        <textarea maxlength="10000" cols="40" rows="8" name="message"
    id="message" class="ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a"
aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Submit</span>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="submit-value"
    class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because the form is also normally submitted.

Change

```
$(form1Var).submit(function() {
```

to

```
$(form1Var).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: This does not work. I put in the code exactly as you said and it is still showing the message in the url.

The element that `form1Var` connects to is `<form name="submit_message"...>` Maybe that's the problem? I don't know.

Comment: Did you change also the first line (declaring e) ? if so, how is exactly declared form1Var ?

Comment: `var form1Var = $('form#message_form');$(form1Var).submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();` is the code. e is declared.

Edit: I just noticed that there is two jQuery functions. Testing it...

Comment: No still same issue, even when I change `$(form1Var)` to `$('form#message_form')`

Comment: Fixed it. I added `return false;` to the end of the `submit()` function and now it's not showing the url.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of `jQuery` post.

You have to prevent the default action or you have to say `return false` Just after submitting the form.